# Insert if Update fails

Tags: sql, h2

Using H2, I want to attempt to update a row.  If it doesn't exist, I'd like to insert it.  **I'd like to do it all in one single SQL statement**, if possible, to avoid concurrency issues.

So far I have the update:

```
UPDATE RATING 
SET NUM_RATINGS = (SELECT NUM_RATINGS + 1 FROM RATING WHERE EVENT_UID = :eventUid)
, SUM_RATINGS = (SELECT SUM_RATINGS + :newRating FROM RATING WHERE EVENT_UID = :eventUid)
WHERE EVENT_UID = :eventUid AND EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM RATING WHERE EVENT_UID = :eventUid)
```

The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE RATING (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
EVENT_UID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
SUM_RATINGS BIGINT NOT NULL, 
NUM_RATINGS INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_UID) REFERENCES EVENT(UID)
)
```

Can anyone improve the Update statement?

How do I, in the same SQL statement, add an Insert like the following, if the row does not exist?

```
INSERT INTO RATING ( ID , EVENT_UID , NUM_RATINGS , SUM_RATINGS ) 
VALUES (2, 'BWEIY-A4', 1, 4)
```

Comment: in oracle, this is called MERGE

Comment: H2 has [MERGE](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge) too.

Comment: merge might do it, but i think i'll remove "id" because its currently set using a JPA table generator.  not sure i really need that.